# Profiles and Approval process in 2GP managed package

Tags: managed-package, package

I am trying to include Profiles and Approval process in my 2GP managed package but the changes are not getting reflected after installing the package.

I read from articles that those two things cant be included and those articles are long year back old.

Still cant we add Profiles and Approval process in 2GP managed package? if not able to means can we able to do through some other way other than 2GP

Comment: For reference, the best source on which components are and are not supported is the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage)

Comment: @David Reed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed Packages are not really meant to include Profiles or Approval Processes. You can package Approval Processes with Unlocked Packages, which could have dependencies on your 2GMP, and you could include Profiles in both UP and 2GMP, but be aware that profiles tend to be really touchy sometimes; I'd recommend a Permission Set instead, if your use case is supported by Permission Sets.

Comment: Note: On package installation, new profiles are not created; instead, the profile snippets are merged into existing profiles in the org for the type specified (i.e., Admins, All Users).
Does it mean that I have to create an empty profile with same name in the package, in the org where I am going to install then after package install my the profile setting will be merged?

Comment: @SFDC-Beginner No, it means no new profiles will be created. Like I said, this should be a Permission Set.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. And this article helped me a lot to sort out the issue. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000353659&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1